# R10 Boot Timeout error while running app on heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, npm, deployment

I have express.js application, and I want to run command build before application starts, but I am getting this error "Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch".

Here is my scripts in package.json

```
"scripts": {
"dev": "concurrently \"webpack --config webpack/client.prod.js --progress --watch\" \"webpack --config webpack/server.prod.js --progress --watch\" \"npm start\"",
"real_dev": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack/client.dev.js",
"build": "npm run build:client && npm run build:server",
"build:server": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack/server.prod.js --progress",
"build:client": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack/client.prod.js --progress",
"start": "cd server && node bin/server.js",
"lint": "eslint --ext .jsx,.js ./"
```

},

Answer (score 0):

Try to use port from env with process.env.PORT instead of static port

Comment: Hope this can help you

Comment: https://help.heroku.com/P1AVPANS/why-is-my-node-js-app-crashing-with-an-r10-error

Comment: I have already set dynamic port process.env.PORT, but app still isn't working

Comment: Any help from https://help.heroku.com/P1AVPANS/why-is-my-node-js-app-crashing-with-an-r10-error